# 正規表現で 数字と漢字が入力必須条件の書き方を教えて欲しい

Tags: 正規表現

ユーザーが住所入力する際に番地の数字漏れを防ぐため
正規表現で 数字と漢字が入力必須条件の書き方を教えて欲しいです。

下記のコードで試しましたが漢字だけでも入力可能なため困っています。

^[0-9一-龠]*$

Comment: 正規表現で漢字(日本語？)扱う場合, 実装毎に異なるので何の言語使用するのか書いたほうがよいかも。たぶん Unicodeだと思うけどencodingについても。また ひらがなやカタカナも含めるのか全角の数字や記号は扱うのかどうかも

Comment: [teratail: 正規表現で 数字と漢字が入力必須条件の書き方を教えて欲しい](https://teratail.com/questions/2n4qm4udwymbul)

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/2n4qm4udwymbul

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> ^[0-9一-龠]*$
> ```

「漢字」の指定が`一-龠`でよいかは一旦おいておきます。(結局意味ないので)

数字と漢字がそれぞれ少なくとも1回現れないといけない、という条件であれば、例えば

```
[一-龠].*[0-9]
```

ですかね。(数字-漢字の順に対応できませんが、住所なのでいきなり数字ってことはない前提)

さて本題は

> 住所入力する際に番地の数字漏れを防ぐ

だと思うのですが、正規表現でのチェックは無駄に厳しくなるかさもなくばザルになるかどっちかなのであまり意味がないです。

例えば上記だと数字をいわゆる「全角」で書かれるとマッチしません。全角数字を条件に入れると、地名そのものに全角数字が入ってるとチェックを通ってしまい入力漏れは防げません。
さらに、世の中には番地がない住所も存在します。

入力漏れが問題なのであれば、文字種のチェックよりもUIを工夫したほうがよいでしょう。が、これはこれでいろいろ大変です。番地欄分けたら分けたでそれによって入力漏れを誘発するとか。

ユーザビリティ含めて考えると住所の入力というのは実はかなり難易度が高い課題ですので、きちんと考えられた方がよいです。